# Lightning component limitaion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, governorlimits

Just wondering -- How many records can be shown on a lightning component without doing the pagination. Do Components have the limitaions just like that of VF pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no hard limit built in to aura:iteration, as there was with the Visualforce iterators. The actual limits will be based on exactly what you're trying to do. For example, SOQL from the server-side is limited to 50,000 rows, so that might be practical limitation in the sense that you'll have to at least paginate the queries.

At some point, rendering will take so long that your browser will crash from lack of memory, scripts taking too long to run, etc. On my computer, a single column table was able to support about 50,000 rows before the rendering time started affecting my system.

Should you decide to do this, remember to test your code on mobile devices to make sure it can actually render the page. Infinite scrolling and pagination are recommended for client-performance reasons, which you should take in to consideration.